# Form field values getting flushed at onclick=window.print()

Tags: javascript, html

I was creating an admission form using Html5 and bootstrap.But i wanted to include a feature that user can take a print out of the page before clicking the submit button.So i applied onclick=window.print() at the click of print button.But to the dismay all the field values gets flushed as soon as print button is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline" id="sunrise" name="sunrise" method="post" action="">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Father's Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="father" placeholder="">
    </div></div> <br/>
     <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Mother's Name:&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mother" placeholder="">
    </div>
    </div>
<br/>   
         <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>DOB:</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" placeholder="">
    </div>
    </div>
    <button type="Print" class="btn btn-default" id="print" onclick="window.print()">Print Application</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>


  </form>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the print button's invalid type to a valid one.

```
<button type="Print" class="btn btn-default" id="print" onclick="window.print()">Print Application</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="print" onclick="window.print()">Print Application</button>
```

Because the "Print" type is invalid, the button has the default behavior inside a form, which is submit, that makes the page to reload.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate wasn't able to figure out this small error.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `type="button"` then to use type="print". because its invalid.

```
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="print" onclick="window.print()">Print Application</button>`
```